# Do "plug multiplier" and "plug splitter" mean the same?

Tags: synonyms

I wonder whether "plug multiplier" and "plug splitter" are equivalent or there are differences in meaning/usage? Both can be bought on Amazon, and the products appear to be the same type.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [GoogleFight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?word1=plug+multiplier&word2=plug+splitter) says ***splitter*** id 5-6 times more common than ***multiplier*** in this context (for *plugs*, at least). But they're the same thing, as you should be able to tell by looking at the products themselves.

Comment: Are you talking about a [**cube tap**](http://www.amazon.com/Cooper-Wiring-Devices-1482W-BOX-Adapter/dp/B000KKHROM)??

Comment: The terms, very generically interpreted, mean the same thing.  As is illustrated below, "multiplier" tends to be used for devices that have more outlets than a "splitter", while "splitter" tends to be used in a more generic sense to include devices that "split" audio/video signals, etc, rather than referring only to power splitters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *[items](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plug%20multiplier)* are *[similar](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_13?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plug%20splitter&sprefix=plug%20splitter%2Caps%2C657&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aplug%20splitter)*, but the expressions employ a description from distinct frames of reference:

> 1. The device ***splits*** the signal between two (or more) lines.

That frame of reference describes the same outcome as:

> 2. The device ***multiplies*** the lines carrying the signal by two (or more).

---

**Amazon USA:**

plug *[multiplier](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plug%20multiplier)* search.
Item at top of search triples the duplex receptacle:  [image]

---

plug *[splitter](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_13?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plug%20splitter&sprefix=plug%20splitter%2Caps%2C657&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aplug%20splitter)* search.
Item at top of search triples the single outlet:  [image]

---

**Amazon UK:**

plug *[multiplier](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_fb_0_8?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plug%20multiplier&sprefix=plug%20mul%2Ckitchen%2C712&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aplug%20multiplier)* search.
Item at top of search quadruples the single socket:  [image]

---

plug *[splitter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_13?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plug%20splitter&sprefix=plug%20splitter%2Ckitchen%2C825&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aplug%20splitter)* search.
Item at top of search doubles the single socket:  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Try these Yahoo searches (just click on the links):

[**"plug splitter" images**](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A0LEVv6QYyBVpi4AkJInnIlQ;_ylc=X1MDMTM1MTE5NTY4NwRfcgMyBGZyAwRncHJpZANKUVZwSVp3SVJQUzZYaUN3eUhVNi5BBG5fcnNsdAMwBG5fc3VnZwMwBG9yaWdpbgNzZWFyY2gueWFob28uY29tBHBvcwMwBHBxc3RyAwRwcXN0cmwDBHFzdHJsAzIyBHF1ZXJ5AyJwbHVnIHNwbGl0dGVyIiBpbWFnZXMEdF9zdG1wAzE0MjgxODYwMzE-?p=%22plug%20splitter%22%20images&fr2=sb-top-search&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-001)

[**"plug multiplier" images**](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=%20%22plug%20multiplier%22%20images&ei=UTF-8&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-001)

They show, to me at least, quite radically differently-looking products :-)

Comment: The OP mentioned Amazon.com specifically :-) The various splitters and multipliers on Yahoo could be sorted out among various technologies, but that would be a chore.